# Sort stacked barplot in decreasing order in R

Tags: r

I am creating a stacked barplot out of a 2x2 table:

```
fuel.type <- c('diesel', 'gas', 'diesel', 'gas', 'diesel', 'gas', 'gas', 'gas', 'gas')   
make <- c('bmw', 'wv', 'audi', 'bmw', 'audi', 'audi', 'wv', 'wv', 'wv')    
table1 <- table(fuel.type, make)  
barplot(table1, legend = row.names(table1))
```

I get the following figure:

[image: stacked barplot]

How can i get the same plot but sorted in decreasing order??

Answer (score 3):

You could sort your data, then plot them, in this way:

```
# here you define a table (your) that is sorted by the total of the columns
table1 <- table1[,order(colSums(-table1))] 
barplot(table1, legend = row.names(table1))
```

[image]